# Método replace no se repite

Tags: javascript, replace, javascript-metodo

Holaa a todos. Como verán tengo el siguiente problema... Hay un input en el cual lo que uno va escribiendo va figurando en el contenedor2, el inconveniente es que cuando borro(con la tecla borrar, "backspace") una letra se borra solo 1 carácter y no todos los demás que borro. Además se ve como el console log de abajo de la linea del replace si se repite en consola, en cambio el método replace solo se realiza 1 vez.  Como podría solucionar esto? Escribo mas porque me pide agregar más detalles sin embargo no creo que sea difícil de entender

```js
let texto = document.getElementById("texto");
let contenedor2 = document.getElementById("contenedor2");
let conetenedorPrueba = document.getElementById("contenedorPrueba");


let contador=0;
let palabra = [];


texto.addEventListener("keyup", (e)=>{
    let letraNueva = e.key;    
    palabra[contador] = letraNueva;
    contador++;
    let palabraCompleta = palabra.toString();
    let nuevaPalabra = palabraCompleta.replace(/,|Backspace/g, "");  
    contenedor2.innerHTML = nuevaPalabra;  
    
    if (letraNueva == "Backspace"){
        let espacios = nuevaPalabra.length;
        contenedor2.innerHTML  = nuevaPalabra.substring(0, espacios-1);
        console.log(nuevaPalabra.length);
    }   
  }
 )
```

```css
#contenedor {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
#contenedor2 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: red;
}
#contenedorPrueba {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: aqua;
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>  
 <div id="contenedor">
    <input type="text" name="" id="texto">
    <div id="contenedor2"></div>
 </div>
 <div id="contenedorPrueba"></div>
    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Sirve reemplazar todo el código complejo que está dentro del listener?

```
texto.addEventListener("keyup", (e)=>{
    // Todo lo que está aquí  
});
```

Por:

```
texto.addEventListener("keyup", (e)=>{
       contenedor2.innerHTML = texto.value;
});
```

```js
let texto = document.getElementById("texto");
let contenedor2 = document.getElementById("contenedor2");
let conetenedorPrueba = document.getElementById("contenedorPrueba");


let contador=0;
let palabra = [];


texto.addEventListener("keyup", (e)=>{
    contenedor2.innerHTML = texto.value;
  }
 )
```

```css
#contenedor {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
#contenedor2 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: red;
}
#contenedorPrueba {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: aqua;
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>  
 <div id="contenedor">
    <input type="text" name="" id="texto">
    <div id="contenedor2"></div>
 </div>
 <div id="contenedorPrueba"></div>
    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: si sirve, es exactamente lo que quería. Estas soluciones simples que no encuentro me hacen sentir tonto.

Comment: Tranquilo, la experiencia va llegando. Para la próxima intenta preguntar aclarando qué es lo que buscas, no cuál es el inconveniente que enfrentaste, porque "Método replace no se repite" no es para nada una buena explicación de tu problema :)